# Jquery not able to set hidden field values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing strange issue while trying to set hidden fields using Jquery and even with plain java-script

I have 2 hidden fields in my JSP page

```
<input type="hidden" name="firstSelectedPaymentId" id="firstSelectedPaymentId1" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="secondSelectedCCPaymentId" id="secondSelectedCCPaymentId" value=""/>
```

and this is how i am setting hidden values in JS

```
if ($('#firstSelectedPaymentId1').length > 0) {
    $('#firstSelectedPaymentId1').val(response.result.selectedPaymentInfoId);
}

if ($('#secondSelectedCCPaymentId').length > 0) {
   //$('#secondSelectedCCPaymentId').val(response.result.selectedPaymentInfoId);            
  document.getElementById('secondSelectedCCPaymentId').value=response.result.selectedPaymentInfoId;
}
```

For the first case it's working fine, but for `secondSelectedCCPaymentId`, it is not setting any value in the hidden field.

I already checked my JSP and there is not field with same id , additionally if i try

```
alert($('#secondSelectedCCPaymentId').val());
```

I am able to see value in alert box like `5466565665666`.`response.result.selectedPaymentInfoId` is a system generated value and it is being generated by the system which i already verified.
I am not sure where i am doing wrong or why it is not setting value in hidden field?

Comment: does `response.result.selectedPaymentInfoId` return any value?

Comment: also what is returned by `alert($('#secondSelectedCCPaymentId').length);`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: yes `response.result.selectedPaymentInfoId` return a value and alert box display that value like `45654566756`.

Comment: `if ($('#firstSelectedPaymentId1').length > 0) {
    $(this).val(response.result.selectedPaymentInfoId);
}` But you can use `this` right?

Comment: @user1671639: we can, but i do not see that as a reason of my issue

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi no, just to know the reason why you haven't used.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you `alert(response.result.selectedPaymentInfoId);`, do you get the same result? Also, maybe there is some weird character being printed that the DOM is not liking.

Comment: @HanletEscaño: There is not a chance if weird character and this is a system generated ID which is numeric, and yes with alert, i am getting same result

Answer (score -2):

```
if ($('#firstSelectedPaymentId1').length > 0) {
    $('#firstSelectedPaymentId1').text(response.result.selectedPaymentInfoId);
}

if ($('#secondSelectedCCPaymentId').length > 0) {
   //$('#secondSelectedCCPaymentId').text(response.result.selectedPaymentInfoId);            
  document.getElementById('secondSelectedCCPaymentId').value=response.result.selectedPaymentInfoId;
}
```

Comment: not sure if that is a solution and how it will going to resolve my issue?

Comment: Can you explain why this is an answer? Hidden textboxes won't utilise a text() property

Comment: we can take value of hidden text field using text() method.

Comment: Really? http://jsfiddle.net/RcqQX/3/ (I also meant to say "hidden form elements", not "hidden textboxes" :|)